# Finding Stackage LTS with right version of base

Tags: haskell, stackage

What is the easiest way of finding an LTS on [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) with the right version of some particular package (in my case `base-4.5.*`).

As of now I've had to resort to finding the right resolver by trial and error, which is cumbersome to say the least.

I've tried searching on Google and the Stackage FAQ, but came up empty-handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major version of base is closely linked to the version of ghc (as you can see on [this wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package)). Since the ghc version only changes on a major version change of LTS, you could always look at each major version and see if one matches (there is on 6).

However, I think you are out of luck, since the first version of stackage, [`lts-1.0`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-1.0), has `ghc-7.8.4` and `base-4.7.0.2`, you won't find any LTS for `base-4.5` on stackage.

Comment: I see, thanks. I tried to bump the version of base instead and it seems to work.